# PHP overloading - avoid Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, overloading

I'm using `__get` and `__set` methods for variable overloading.

In some cases I will assign another object to a variable, for example:

```
$object->name->another = $another_object;
```

`$object`, has the `__get` and `__set` methods.  When I try to access `$object->name->another` before it's been set, I get the error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Is there anyway around this using overloading? without having to check isset on the variable.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using `isset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `$object` but `$object->name` needs to have the overloading with `__get()`/`__set()` if you want to interact to prevent the error in question:

```
$object->name->another = 'something';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For example you can make `$object::__get()` return an empty `stdClass` object, PHP would then automatically assign a public member to it in this case.

Comment: Hmm.. would I have to define specifically which key to return as an empty stdClass? Is there a way to dynamically do this?

Comment: Well you could return on all keys, as you just want to prevent the error and PHP will automatically add the next missing member.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't answer your question, it addresses an important aspect:

It's worth noting that you ought not allow your magic `__get` and `__set` methods to raise that notice. The "best practice" is to throw one of the new(ish) SPL Exception types specifically designed for this purpose. For example:

```
public function __get($name)
{      
  if (isset($this->vals[$name])) {
    return $this->vals[$name];
  } else {
    $msg = "Invalid property: '$name' does not exist";
    throw new OutOfBoundsException($msg);
  }
}
```

And for __set ...

```
public function __set($name, $val)
{      
  if (isset($this->vals[$name])) {
    $this->vals[$name] = $val;
  } else {
    $msg = "Invalid property: '$name' does not exist";
    throw new OutOfBoundsException($msg);
  }
}
```

Here's [a link to a helpful article](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/05/06/how-to-use-built-in-spl-exception-classes-for-better-error-handling/) on the subject of the new SPL Exception types.

Comment: So with this you will use $object->name['another'] instead of $object->name->another?

Comment: No, this is just an example implementation where you store and access your magic properties in a protected $vals property of your class. The other posted answers correctly assess your problem: The entity you're assigning to `$object->name` should be an actual object with a `$another` property

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are returning an overloaded class for "name". PHP will fetch the property, then try to set the second property on the resulting object.

```
<?php
class Bob {
    public function __get($name) {
        return new Jim();
    }
}
class Jim extends Bob {
    public function __get($name) {
        return 12;
    }
}

$b = new Bob();
echo $b->someJim->apples;
```